# como puedo desplegar un input tipo date, pero que solo aparezca como opción años?

Tags: php, html

necesito obtener dato de un input pero solo necesito el año, y quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de que solo despliegue años, en vez de el datepicker del input date de html:5

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El `input` de tipo `date` , se pensó para las fechas si usted solo desea el año, debería analizar otras opciones como `input` tipo `number` quizá.

Comment: Puedes hacer un select option con todos los años que necesites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente no hay un `type` de `input` que permita seleccionar sólo años. Sin embargo puedes realizar un `<select>` con los años que puedas necesitar, aquí te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como hacer uno con un ciclo PHP y HTML.

```
<?php
$cont = date('Y');
?>
<select id="sel1">
<?php while ($cont >= 1950) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo($cont); ?>"><?php echo($cont); ?></option>
<?php $cont = ($cont-1); } ?>
</select>
```

Puedes cambiar el **1950** por cualquier año desde el que quieras comenzar la cuenta, lo pongo en orden descendente porque así es como se suele utilizar.
Espero te ayude :)

Comment: gracias, me sirvió para lo que necesitaba

Comment: Si te sirvió, te invito a que marques la respuesta como "Aceptada" para ayudar a más personas con el mismo problema a obtener una solución, gracias :)